# How do you make it in roblox studio when you get a kill , it says "you killed this player" or whatever?

Tags: scripting, roblox

**I want to make it whenever you get a kill it will say " You killed (playername)"**

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: In your sword script before TakeDamage, if you wanted to do a gui, you would create a textlabel under the gui with you "killed " , put under your sword, then clone it to playergui, then change the text to "You killed" .. hit.Parent.Name (replace hit with what variable it uses for takedamage)